# How do you test to see if UIActivityIndicatorView is spinning when the app runs smoothly?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview, ios12

My issue is that you cannot see the `UIActivityIndicatorView` because the app runs smoothly so I am not sure if the code is right.

Here is everything that mentions it:

```
@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var progressBar: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped.toggle()
    nextQuestion()
}

func startOver() {
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
    questionNumber = 0
    score = 0
    nextQuestion()
}

func nextQuestion() {
    updateUI()
    loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
    if questionNumber <= 12 {

func updateUI() {

        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"

        progressBar.frame.size.width = (view.frame.size.width / 13) * CGFloat(questionNumber)


    }
```

This is not in order.

Comment: What's the point of the activity indicator? The code in `nextQuestion` and `updateUI` will happen far too quickly to justify its use.

Comment: I'm just playing around
But it was slower before I added the activity indicator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can artificially add a delay to `nextQuestion()` with either:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
    self?.nextQuestion()
}
```

or

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
    self?.nextQuestion()
}
```

The delay will allow you to see the timer spinning.  A better approach is to hide your service layer behind a protocol then you can have a mock service layer that returns sample data after a delay or that errors out.  This lets you test thing like loading animations as well as error handling.

Comment: You can more simply use `DispatchQueue.main.async`. No need to wait the extra second.

Answer (score 0):

just to check if it is working you can use breakpoint one the line where activityindicator starts animating 
you can also use timer

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeat: false){ (timer) in
//start animating here 
}
```